# How to specify Maven local repository if I cannot use default Maven local repository settings?

Tags: maven, jenkins

we have restrictions on size of the $HOME and therefore I cannot use default settings ~/.m2/  We use in per-job configuration "use private maven repository" option. What to do if job 2 is dependent on an artifact produced by job 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution for the command line is to give it via command line:

```
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=WhereEverYouLikeToHaveYourRepo
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using maven directly (through commandline maybe) than create a `settings.xml` within the `conf` directory of your maven. This `settings.xml` should look like:

```
<settings>
    <localRepository>C:\Repository</localRepository>
</settings>
```

If you're working with Eclipse than place the `settings.xml` wherever you want and go within Eclipse to `Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings` and set `User Settings` with the path to your `settings.xml`.

Comment: and what if we use Maven via Jenkins jobs?

Comment: Checkout the config files plugin for Jenkins. It allows you to centrally manage your Maven settings files and associate them with a Maven build job.